# How can I stash some files and commit to a new branch the rest?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-stash

In a git repos I do:
`git status` and I see:

```
somepath/file1  
somepath/file2  
somepath/file3  
somepathotherpath/file4  
somepathdifferentpath/fileX  
somepathotherpath/fileY  
somepath/fileZ
```

Checked out as modified. There is also a file just added and not tracked.
What I want to do is the following:
I want to somehow stash e.g. 3 of the files and for the rest create and switch to a new branch and commit them.
So the final result will be 3 of the files will be checkout in git status in the master branch and the rest would be the top commit of a new branch.
Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

`git stash --patch` (short version: `git stash -p`)
Will allow you to interactively select hunks to stash

`git add --patch` (short version: `git add -p`)
Will allow you to interactively select hunks to add to the index

So do this:

1. Stash the 3 you want. (see above)
2. Checkout your new branch.  i.e.  `git co -b new_branch`
3. Add new changes to index that you want to commit (see above)
4. Commit new changes.  i.e. `git commit -m "stuff"`